# Python Selenium click function does not perform any action, test is not failing

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, automation, webdriver

I write automated test in Python using Selenium webdriver and for one element the function click() does not perform any action. But the test does not even fail (e.g. for no such element or not clickable,..)

My code:

```
def fill_applications_tab(self):
    wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20)
    wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@name='application' and text()[contains(.,'JBoss')]]/parent::*/parent::tr/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox' and @name='man']")))
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@name='application' and text()[contains(.,'JBoss')]]/parent::*/parent::tr/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox' and @name='man']").click()
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-sm-12" id="appl_applications_mw_error_div">
                <table class="table white table-condensed table-bordered tight-col">
                    <thead>
                        <tr class="app-table-descr">
                            <td colspan="7">Middleware</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <th class="t-center">Install</th>
                            <th>Application name</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody class="sort">
                        <tr class="show-info" name="appl_applications_mw" data-type="array" data-tab-id="#tab-app" data-upform-error="#appl_applications_mw_error_div" data-show-info-field="man">
                            <td class="form-group-sm">
                                <span name="version" data-type="arrayitem" disabled="disabled">2.0.x (HP)</span>
                            </td>
                        </tr><tr class="show-info" name="appl_applications_mw" data-type="array" data-tab-id="#tab-app" data-upform-error="#appl_applications_mw_error_div" data-show-info-field="man">
                            <td class="t-center">
                                <input name="type" type="hidden" data-type="arrayitem" value="mw">
                                <input class="show-info-field" name="man" type="checkbox" data-type="arrayitem">
                                <input class="app-man-default hidden" name="man_default" type="checkbox" data-type="arrayitem">
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <span name="application" data-type="arrayitem">JBoss</span>
                            </td>
```

Any idea how to fix it?
I already tried to add the click() action twice in the code (found somewhere as a solution for someone), but it didn't help..
Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure, you are locating correct element??

Comment: Ans FYI `EC.element_to_be_clickable` also returns same element if condition try, so need to find again the same element, remove the last line of code ans just try as `wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//span[@name='application' and text()[contains(.,'JBoss')]]/ancestor::tr//input[@type='checkbox' and @name='man']"))).click()` and let me know..:)

Comment: I guess I am locating the element correctly, because if I use the xpath in chrome console to find the element, the exactly the checkbox is found, so it should be OK. When I remove my code and replace it by yours, it returns TimeoutException

Comment: But you'r finding same element just two time while it can be handle only in once, try above commented code and let me know..:)

Comment: As written above, when I use your code I got a TimeoutException..

Comment: Ok try once using `execute_script()` to perform click as `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click()",driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[@name='application' and text()[contains(.,'JBoss')]]/parent::*/parent::tr/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox' and @name='man']")` and let me know

Comment: In this case I have: SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string '//span[@nam
\u200c\u200be='application' and text()[contains(.,'JBoss')]]/ancestor::tr//input
[@type='chec\u200c\u200bkbox' and @name='man']' is not a valid XPath expression. ==> I am not sure why some parts of the string are replaced by "\u200c\u200b" -> in code it is ok, without this..

Comment: Need to verify xpath then, I think this is copy paste issue, need to write manually

Comment: The xpath just must be ok, because if I use this in console: var btn = $x("//span[@name='application' and text()[contains(.,'JBoss')]]/parent::*/parent::tr/td[1]/input[@type='checkbox' and @name='man']");

btn[0].click(); it works and the element is clicked...currently I am trying to use that js in my python script...but struggling a bit :D Thanks for helping!

Comment: I have provided it as an answer try it and let me know..:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it started to work when I add another different action after save_button.click() 
So the code is like:

```
element_xpath.click()
save_button.click()
navigate_to_another_tab.click()
```

After that the checkbox is chosen and the True is saved